# Datadog: filter by the date in the query widget

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I would like to create the widget that shows the number of entities with the tag `a.b.c` that are created more than 1 week ago. How can I do this?

Should I create a tag with timestamp? How can I filter out the values using it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Creating a tag with timestamp is not a good idea since it increases the cardinality of your metric and increases your bill. Buy the number of entities, are you referring to different metrics or 1 specific metric?